# django: invalid syntax path('details/<int:id>/', views.details, name='details')

Tags: django, django-urls

## views.py file

```
def details(request, id):
post = Posts.objects.get(id=id)

context = {
    'post': post
}

return render(request, 'posts/details.html', context)
```

## urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='index')
   path('details/<int:id>/', views.details, name='details')
]
```

path('details//', views.details, name='details')
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You forgot a comma at the end of the first `path(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
   path('details/<int:id>/', views.details, name='details')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a comma after the first path statement 
Also just a suggestion :

I assume your app is called blog then there are two ways you can approach the above problem :

1. Either declare a function which automatically generated a url from models which includes slug id etc etc or
2. Make a get request from the html itself and then you don't need to specify  after detail and you can directly capture url for id from views.py

Answer (score 0):

Just put comma after each line!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, see how do I write an answer [answer].